# Powershell: Tuples list for each in wrong order?

Tags: powershell, foreach, tuples

I am trying to write to a txt file in a specific order using a list of tuples. the list is ordered by item1 (a number) and has an associated string as item2.

Using a for each loop I have attempted to run though the list and insert the associated string into a txt file. I want the for each loop to iterate through the list using item1, however the for each loop iterates using item2 and inserts in alphabetical order.

How do I make sure it inserts the notes in the correct order?

$sortedList contains:

```
Item1 Item2  Length
----- -----  ------
    0 noteC       2
    1 noteD       2
    2 noteF       2
    3 noteA       2
    4 noteB       2
    5 note5       2
```

D:\ Drive Contains:

```
noteA.pdf
noteB.pdf
noteC.pdf
noteD.pdf
noteF.pdf
note5.pdf
```

Simplified version of what I am doing:

```
$notePath = "D:\"

$list = Get-ChildItem -Path $notePath -Recurse | `
        Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer -eq $false -and $_.Extension -ne '.srt' }

$sortedList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
ForEach($n in $list){
    if($n.name.Contains('C')) {
        $sortedList.Add([Tuple]::Create(0,$n.Name))
    } elseif($n.name.Contains('D')) {
        $sortedList.Add([Tuple]::Create(1,$n.Name))
    } elseif($n.name.Contains('F')) {
        $sortedList.Add([Tuple]::Create(2,$n.Name))
    } elseif($n.name.Contains('A')) {
        $sortedList.Add([Tuple]::Create(3,$n.Name))
    } elseif($n.name.Contains('B')) {
        $sortedList.Add([Tuple]::Create(4,$n.Name))
    } elseif($n.name.Contains('5')) {
        $sortedList.Add([Tuple]::Create(5,$n.Name))
    }
}

New-Item $notePath’\noteList.txt'

ForEach($n in $sortedList){
        $var = "Note:"+ $n.Item2 | Out-File -Append $notePath’\noteList.txt'
}
```

Results in txt file:

```
Note: noteA
Note: noteB
Note: noteC
Note: noteD
Note: noteF
Note: note5
```

Results I want in txt:

```
Note: noteC
Note: noteD
Note: noteF
Note: noteA
Note: noteB
Note: note5
```

Comment: I get 2 errors when I run your code: ```Missing expression after ','.``` for the ```[Tuple]::Create( ... ))``` llines and ```Missing 'in' after variable in foreach loop.``` for  ```ForEach($n.Item1 in $sortedList){ ... }```. Can you confirm your code *as posted* actually runs on your machine?

Comment: Do you have a specific requirement where you have to use tuples?  Maybe try using hash tables `@{0 = 'noteC' }` or dictionary `[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[int],[string]]]::new()` instead?

Comment: `ForEach($n.Item1 in $sortedList)` ... that is syntactically not valid Powershell code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sticking with the Tuple theme, you just need to use `Sort-Object` to re-order your results before you process them:

- Build the test data:

```
$unsortedList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$unsortedList.Add([Tuple]::Create(3, "noteA"))
$unsortedList.Add([Tuple]::Create(4, "noteB"))
$unsortedList.Add([Tuple]::Create(0, "noteC"))
$unsortedList.Add([Tuple]::Create(1, "noteD"))
$unsortedList.Add([Tuple]::Create(2, "noteF"))
$unsortedList.Add([Tuple]::Create(5, "note5"))

$unsortedList | format-table
#Item1 Item2 Length
#----- ----- ------
#    3 noteA      2
#    4 noteB      2
#    0 noteC      2
#    1 noteD      2
#    2 noteF      2
#    5 note5      2
```

- Sort the data

```
$sortedList = $unsortedList | sort-object -Property "Item1";

$sortedList | format-table
#Item1 Item2 Length
#----- ----- ------
#    0 noteC      2
#    1 noteD      2
#    2 noteF      2
#    3 noteA      2
#    4 noteB      2
#    5 note5      2
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, Thank you very much!